# Unordered set in C++, why is hash needed?

Tags: c++, hash, set

I just want to store a couple of objects in an unordered set.
Creating a few sets,

```
auto set1 = std::unordered_set<Myclass>();
```

I sometimes get errors like this, a lot:

> Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::hash'

Is there no other alternative to unordered_set that will work out of the box? And why is "hash" needed?

Comment: Basically this means you have not provided any way to hash `MyClass`. You could use `std::set` instead, with pretty much the same interface but different performance characteristics. Then you will need to provide some ordering function for `MyClass`.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. In what way can this question be improved?

Answer (score 6):

`std::unordered_set` indexes the values in its storage by hashing the key you use, much like a hash table or the C++ `std::unordered_map` implementation.

If you don't want to write a hash function for `Myclass`, just use `std::set` instead. This might perform worse than if you defined a hash function and used `std::unordered_set`, but might be worth it if writing a hash function would be difficult for your class. Depends on the class and your application.

If you want to use `std::unordered_set`, you need to provide a hash function for `Myclass`. Either provide a specialization of `std::hash` for your class, or provide a hashing policy to `std::unordered_set`.

```
//specialize std::hash
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<Myclass>
    {
        typedef Myclass argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;

        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        {
            //some code to hash a Myclass object
        }
    };
}
auto set1 = std::unordered_set<Myclass>();   

//hashing policy version
class MyclassHash
{
public:
    std::size_t operator()(Myclass const& s) const 
    {
        //some code to hash a Myclass object
    }
};
auto set1 = std::unordered_set<Myclass, MyclassHash>();
```